# Django: get data in included template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have one silly Django template question; want to create simple sidebar with last "news" and include it in multiple pages in my website. So i do something like this:

```
# views.py 
def right_sidebar_news(request):
    e = Entry.objects.last()
    return render(request, "_right_sidebar_news.html", {"entry": e})
```

I include _right_sidebar_news.html in my templates like this:

```
# some_theme.html
<!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
{% include "_right_sidebar_news.html" %}
<!-- END RIGHT COLUMN -->
```

But in almost all pages (except entry details of course) variable "entry" is empty.
I know about `with` statement  but in this case i must load last "entry" in all my views.

Any idea how i create this simple sidebar and feel it with data? Thanks.

Comment: does the right_sidebar_news.html renders in template???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) are for.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have your data in `right_sidebar_news` view?
You have to have your desired `Entry` objects in all templates that include `_right_sidebar_news.html` so that this `Entry` could be rendered.
I'd go in a class-based view:

```
class EntriesViewMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntriesViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'last_entry': Entry.objects.last()})
        return context

class SomeView(EntriesViewMixin, TemplateView):
    template_view = 'some_theme.html'
```

But I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly.
Hope that helped :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i already find a solution. The right way is to use custom templatetag.